# how to get current year to date and prior year to date in sql

Tags: sql

Suppose my date range is current: 01-jan-2015 to 17-Feb-2015.

I need the data for 01-jan-2014 to 17-02-2014 also.

how to write the query in sql?

i want to get the data for these CYD and pYD.

Comment: Use BETWEEN in SQL SERVER.

Comment: I think he's asking for a `global macro variable` like solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it go? Table definitions, sample data and wanted result may also increase the chance to get helped.

Comment: Plenty of how-to's on the net and also questions on stackoverflow covering this.

Comment: Which SQL You are using Oracle? SQL Server? My SQL?

Comment: Two down-votes? That's harsh! I came her looking for the same thing. I basically want to have a WHERE clause that will SELECT year-to-this-date data for all prior years.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Oracle :

```
select sysdate - interval '1' year from dual;
```

The key word 'interval' also exist in other SQL language, like postgres.

Answer (score 0):

To select those ranges of dates from, say, a calendar table, I'd probably write this in standard SQL.

```
select cal_date from calendar
where cal_date between date '2015-01-01' 
                   and current_date
   or cal_date between date '2015-01-01' - interval '1' year 
                   and current_date - interval '1' year
order by cal_date;
```

If I wanted to identify rows in each range, I'd add literal values.

```
select 'cyd', cal_date
from calendar
where cal_date between date '2015-01-01' 
                   and current_date
union all
select 'pyd', cal_date 
from calendar
where cal_date between date '2015-01-01' - interval '1' year 
                   and current_date - interval '1' year
order by cal_date;
```